# How to implement custom security trimmer?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, security-trimming, result-source

How can we implement Custom security trimmer (Pre/Post) for SharePoint search result sources ?
Because According to [Link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-use-a-custom-security-trimmer-for-sharepoint-server-search-results#set-up-a-custom-security-trimmer-project%22Link%22)

custom security trimmer will be applicable for whole search service application.

We need a security trimmer which can be used for Search Result sources only .